# Show (or disprove) that this series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers with $a_n>0 $ $ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show (or disprove) this statement:

If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then there exists a sequence $c_n$ of real numbers with $c_n \geq 0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}c_n=\infty$, so that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_na_n$ converges.

I tried many examples and I always found a $c_n$, I have a good feeling that this statement might be true, I can be wrong tho. Does someone have a tip, how to show this? I tried applying several Convergence-Criteria, but it didn't really work out that well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried $c_n = \ln(a_n)$? I think it might work.

Comment: For each $k > 0$ there is an $n_k$ such that $$\sum_{n = n_k}^{\infty} a_n < \frac{1}{k^3}\,.$$